# How to send mail with attachement in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is my complete code of php mail.  My code is working fine but I want to include file as attachement. Where should i add which code to send mail with attachement. No new code is needed. I want to use the same code. can any one find it out and fix it.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
      $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
      $file_name1 = rand().$file_name;
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
      
      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"cv/".$file_name1);
      
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
        
        if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        
        $CV = $_REQUEST['fileToUpload'];
        $Name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $Email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $Mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'];
        $CGPA = $_REQUEST['cgpa'];
        $RegNo = $_REQUEST['regno'];
        $Position = $_REQUEST['position'];
        $Why = $_REQUEST['why'];
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `ExecutiveBody`(`ID`, `CV`, `Name`, `Email`, `Mobile`, `CGPA`, `RegNo`, `Position`, `Why`) VALUES ('','$file_name1','$Name','$Email','$Mobile','$CGPA','$RegNo','$Position','$Why')";
        
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo "<script>alert('Thanks For Your Interest. Check Your Email For Confirmation.');</script>";
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Hush! Sorry $sql. "
                . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        
        
         $to = "mail@hotmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_REQUEST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
     $mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'];
      $cgpa = $_REQUEST['cgpa'];
       $regno = $_REQUEST['regno'];
        $position = $_REQUEST['position'];
         $why = $_REQUEST['why'];
          $cv = $_REQUEST['cv'];
          
    $subject = "Executive Body | Application";
    $subject2 = "Copy Of Your Executive Body Application Submission";
    $message = "<b>Name: </b>" . $name . "<br><br>" . "<b>Email: </b>" . $from . "<br><br>" ."<b>Mobile: </b>" .  $mobile . "<br><br>" . "<b>CGPA: </b>" . $cgpa . "<br><br>" . "<b>Reg No: </b>" . $regno . "<br><br>" . "<b>Position: </b>" . $position . "<br><br>" . "<b>Why You Want To Be Part Of Society?: </b><br><br>" . $why;
    
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    
    $headers .= "From:" . $from;
    
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    
        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($conn);
      
   }
?>
```

Comment: I have done attachments with PHP `mail()`, but using a mail service, or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is a lot easier.

Comment: I have another link to you. I suggest to read the highly ranked answers with their comments. I suggest also the `PHPMailer` instead of the pure PHP `mail()`.